# Why is this event handler being called over 400 times when it's only listened to 20 times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

Briefing on whats happening:
* this.lobbyEvents EventEmitter emits 'lobby-finished' on lobby finish
* on lobby init, the following code is run for every player in the lobby:

```
playerInfoSet.forEach(p => {
  if (p.is_bot == true) {
    let newPlayer = new Player(p._id, p, true, this.playerCB);
    this.playerMap.set(p._id, newPlayer);
    this.activePlayers.push(newPlayer);
    botCount++;
  }

  // remove playerInfoSet data for lobby afterwards to stop re-connect to dead lobby.
  this.lobbyEvents.on('lobby-finished', () => {
    tempcount++;
    console.log(`Player deleted ${p._id}?: ${playerInfoSet.delete(p)}, temp count: ${tempcount}`);
  })
})
```

The output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tokD.png)

This output continues until count 484.
Notice how when the output changes to false for deleted, the value of the player ID is now the same as the first output which was true.
In other words, the EventEmitter isn't working as I expect it to. I expect it to add a listening event ONCE PER PLAYER, instead it seems to be listening MANY TIMES per player!

Note: InitLobby is only called ONCE. Initlobby contains the playerInfoSet && associated code. PlayerInfoSet only has one of each player.

Thanks!

Comment: `new Player(p._id, p, true, this.playerCB;` is syntactically invalid. Please make sure to post your exact real code.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think the reason is because the event is fired for every player when one of the players leave the lobby, which means all players will receive the event more than once.

Comment: John, the event is ONLY called when 0 players are left in the lobby, aka all players have placed and lobby is ready to remove references for garbage collection.

Comment: I figured out my issue, I had placed that event within a loop by mistake when I intended to place it outside of. Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
Make sure to place event calling code outside of loop... heh. Look for silly mistakes!